# Make equal squares with image ratio fixed without any scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to have a dynamic number of boxes, each row has a maximum of 3 boxes.
Each box contains an image, and I need to keep the image with a fixed ratio (These images are actually a video stream, the src of the image will be replaced 30 times each second).

All that said, I also need to avoid any vertical or horizontal scrolling, the box can be resized and the image inside needs to keep the ratio aspect fixed, leaving a blank background from the top / bottom / left / right as necessary. I don't have a static height and width of the videos, it's dynamic.

When I resize the window, I get the result I want, but if I switch to full screen, I get scrolling and not all the boxes fit into the browser. I want all the boxes to be in the browser without any scrolling. The boxes shrink, but KEEP the ratio aspect of the images.

I managed to create the start, using grid-column and grid-row, but I still have the scrolling issue. Does anybody have any solution for this? I don't mind using JavaScript to calculate stuff if needed.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 4em;
      color: #000000;
      background: #ffffff;
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 8px;
      padding: 8px;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #333333;
    }
    .wrapper>div {
      background-color: #333333;
    }
    .item1 {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }
    .item2 {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }
    .item3 {
      grid-column: 3/3;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }
    .item4 {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .item5 {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .item6 {
      grid-column: 3/3;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }
    .item7 {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      grid-row: 3/3;
    }
    .item8 {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 3/3;
    }
    .item9 {
      grid-column: 3/3;
      grid-row: 3/3;
    }
    .item {
      border: 1px red solid;
    }
    .camera-style {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item item1">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item2">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item3">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item4">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item5">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item6">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item7">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item8">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item9">
      <div class="camera-style">
        <img src="https://osrfgtie1.office.osrenterprises.com/resources?rid=aef7c00cf8aa119d9ab413f6a21860971ab7d5a76a4deefc9aa28afb2aca0f33&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoubsecure-s.akamaihd.net%2Fget%2Fb99%2Fp%2Fcoub%2Fsimple%2Fcw_image%2Fc27abea443a%2F7f0e6650b89bcb9801efb%2Fmed_1476219692_00018.jpg&cid=b3IuYXNzYXlhZ0BPU1JET00uTE9DQUw1__FGL__93159432a0683b9b903677cc15e9e07c28ccfc5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000&eid=4" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83Lr45oy/